# Ubuntu 17.10: Firefox/Google Chrome extensions not in sync with GNOME Tweak Tool extensions

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-tweak-tool

"windows list:" and others are checked while on my desktop none are even installed.

[image]

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshot it seems you're in a "GNOME Classic" session.

In GNOME Classic session it doesn't matter what it shows, extensions like "Window List", "Application Menu", "Places Status Indicator" are always activated by default. It doesn't even provide the user an easy option to disable them (try disabling/enabling any of the aforementioned extensions, you'll see no change).

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to the settings button and choose Options from the menu, and in the Personal Stuff tab check “Use system title bar and borders“ under Appearance. Above it you can also click the Use GTK+ theme button, and the rest of Google Chrome will be themed with the colours, textures and buttons of your current system theme.